# Fusion charts not showing up with Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fusioncharts

Hi i am not able to show up Fusion charts using RoR 2.3.5, just trying to showup the single_series array method for 3d bar graph

Anybody has similar issue ? please help

Answer (score 0):

Please see a sample application posted at [FusionCharts in RoR 2.3.5](http://www.fusioncharts.com/forum/Topic27405-34-1.aspx)